# A doubt about real analysis concerning countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I sometimes get confused when dealing with the notion of countable sets. MY book says that $A$ I countable if there is bijection $f: A \to \mathbb{N }$. but then I frequently see people refer to countable sets only if $f$ is injective.

So, my question is: if there is an injection between $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ does it imply that $A$ must be countable ?

Comment: For some people, "countable" means that there is a bijection, and for them, a finite set is not countable. For others, "countable" means that there is an injection, and for them a finite set is also countable

Comment: You can see this question is [like yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345716/real-definition-of-countable-set)

Comment: How can we prove that if we have injective $f: A \to \mathbb{N} $, then $A$ is countable ?

Comment: As @Tryss says, if, for you, “countable” implies “infinite”, then it’s *not true* that an injection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$ implies countability of $A$.

Comment: I mean a set is countable if it is denumerable or finite. This is my definition I learnt

Comment: You may have learned that $0$ is not a natural number; but in some contexts it is! Or you may have learned that $0$ is not a prime number, but in some contexts it is (the ideal $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Z$). Definitions are context dependent, when it's easier to include finite sets in the definition, we do that and it's easier to exclude them we do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, here’s the solution to your problem. Let $A$ be a set with an injection $f$ into $\Bbb N$. If $A$ is finite, it’s countable according to your definition.

If, on the other hand, $A$ is infinite, then you need to show that $A$ has a subset in one-to-one correspondence with $\Bbb N$. That is, you want an injective map $g:\Bbb N\to A$. To get such a thing, pick an element $x_0$ of $A$ (being nonfinite, $A$ is nonempty). Since $A$ is nonfinite, $A\setminus\{x_0\}$ is still nonempty, and has an element $x_1$. Continue this way, getting a map $g:\Bbb N\to A$, by $g(n)=x_n$. I’m sure a careful proof of this requires an appeal to the Axiom of Choice.

But now that you have injections going both ways between $A$ and $\Bbb N$, you call in Bernstein’s Theorem, which finds a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $A$.

You see that all the above argument calls in some relatively heavy artillery from elementary Set Theory, and maybe you can see why people have just asked you to *believe* that for countability of $A$, it’s enough to have an injection from $A$ into $\Bbb N$.